# How to call a view element from controller

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs4.1

I have a radarChart in my view, where I have two fields xField and yField. These two work as two axis of a radar chart. Now I have to  get those two fields in my controller. I am using Ext.ComponentQuery.query but I cannot use it properly. Here is my code ..

```
  series: [{
    type: 'radar',
    xField: 'Name',
    yField: 'Data',
    showInLegend: false,
    showMarkers: true,
    markerConfig: {
        radius: 4,
        size: 4,
        fill: 'rgb(212, 40, 40)'
    },
    style: {
        fill: 'rgb(94, 114, 13)',
        opacity: 0.5,
        'stroke-width': 0.5
    }
}]
```

and the controller is ..

```
      init : function() {
        this.control({

    'radarChart':{

      click:function(){

         var name=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#')[1];
         alert(name);
      }

    }
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you are trying to get the xField, but this should work:

```
var name = Ext.getCmp('radarChart').series.items[0].xField;
```